# ICS file in gmail - EXDATE (excluding dates) does not work in gmail

Tags: calendar, gmail, icalendar

I have ics file with EXDATE and this not work for gmail.
It works in outlook but gmail add calendar event also for dates that are excluded.
This is known issue or I have some bugs in ics?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID: something
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Oslo
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Oslo
TZURL:http://tzurl.org/zoneinfo-outlook/Europe/Oslo
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Oslo
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:CEST
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:CET
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=Some:mailto:some@some.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE;CN=some@some.com:mailto:some@some.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:
SUMMARY:Test
DTSTAMP:20210331T112255
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210305T060000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210305T133000
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20210308T060000;INTERVAL=1
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210306T123000
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210307T123000
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

another EXDATE also not works for gmail but works in outlook

```
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210306T123000,20210307T123000
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Google is a bit fussier - wants better files.  Run yours through all the ica validators you can find.  
Pasting your ics code into https://icalendar.org/validator.html I get:
Warnings: 
    Line length should not be longer than 75 characters near line # 26
Errors
    Missing UID property near line # 24

Comment: Then on http://ical-validator.herokuapp.com  for your code, I get:

! CRLF should be used for newlines
Related RFC 5545 section: 3.1
For the VTIMEZONE: ! Property [DTSTART] must be specified once

and then

! Property [UID] must be specified once
Related RFC 5545 section: 3.8.4.7
! DATE-TIME value in [DTSTAMP] must be specified in UTC time
Related RFC 5545 section: 3.8.7.2